# Is Ubuntu using my Graphics card?

Tags: ati, graphics, radeon

So i have a AMD CPU with Radeon HD 3200 as integrated graphics, and i recently found a All-In-Wonder AMD Graphics card (pretty old) and used it but im not sure if ubuntu is using it, or if it's still using the Radeon HD 3200. When i look at the info about this computer within ubuntu it says my grahpics is: Gallium 0.4 on AMD RV635. Help?

Comment: Google AMD RV635, it looks like a discrete graphic card.

Answer (score 0):

Check your graphics card:

```
lspci | grep -Pi 'vga|3d|2d'
```

*Sample output*

```
01:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation GK104GLM [Quadro K5000M] (rev a1)
```

Now get more informations with:

```
sudo lspci -v -s 01:00.0
```

Check the entry `Kernel driver`

---

An other way:

```
sudo lshw -c video
```

*Sample output*

```
  *-display               
       description: VGA compatible controller
       product: 3rd Gen Core processor Graphics Controller
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 2
       bus info: pci@0000:00:02.0
       version: 09
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: msi pm vga_controller bus_master cap_list rom
       configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
       resources: irq:45 memory:c0000000-c03fffff memory:b0000000-bfffffff ioport:3000(size=64)
```

Check the used driver with

```
LANG=C sudo lshw -c video | grep configuration
```

*Sample output*

```
configuration: driver=i915 latency=0
```

And check the details, eg

```
modinfo i915
```